# Only install specific driver from linux-modules-extra

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, usb-installation, serial-port

I have a USB serial cable that I'm trying to connect to a Ubuntu 20.04 machine (kernel Linux 5.8.0-63-generic). To get the ttyUSB0 in /dev I have to do a `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`, which installs a lot of extra drivers I simply don't need. Is there a way to only install the specific driver?

`lsusb` shows the serial port as following;

> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303
> Serial Port

the file that I need from linux-modules-extra is

> .../drivers/usb/serial/pl2303.ko

Comment: `linux-modules-extra` are installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 20.04?   The kernel you mention is *unsupported* in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS so I'll suggest upgrading your system asap (*you're more than a year behind on security fixes!*) OR you're using a Ubuntu 20.04 based system and not Ubuntu at all.  Please clarify?  (The 5.8 kernel was from [20.10 which is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/) with 20.04 systems upgrading to using the kernel from 21.04 (5.11), 21.10 (5.13) etc if using the HWE stack).